Rotation of object buggy when animated along a curve
Recently I have been working on an asset which allows a user to animate arrows along a curve. I have been utilizing geometry nodes for this, and have run into some trouble.
Here is the basic setup:

The idea is that the arrows continuously spawn and displace along a curve. It is important to note that the arrow does not deform along the bends of the curve.
I have run into the problem where the arrow object rotation start bugging out after a while.
If i let the animation run for a bit then this happens with the arrows:

I have also noticed that this unwanted rotation correlates with the length of the curve that the arrows spawn on.
I probably have some of the math mixed up that drives the continuous movement of the arrows, but have been unable to solve this problem.
Any help, or tips are appreciated!
And here is the blend file:


Please share your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ rather than a site where it will not remain available. This will allow people researching your question in future to still be able to see your file.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it. Thanks.

Capturing the attributes for the position and tangent, before using the Set Position node, ensures that they are both evaluated at the same time. If you don't capture them first, then the set position node is applied, then it samples the curve again for the tangent on the curve with the strange new positions. This is why you are ending up with strange rotational artifacts.
I simplified the rotation calculation for you.

As well as simplifying the looping using a Wrap on the math node.


I also found another method to fix this problem, and that is to utilize the Sample Index node.
Here is the relevant node setup:

